# Numbers whose square root is whole number, without a math library

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers, square-root

I'm struggling with this problem, I need to find and show in the console all the numbers, whose square root is a whole number, without using math library. It's in C so I can't use math.h and I don't think I actually need an algorithm like Babylon towers or something, or do I need one?

Comment: Just print 1², 2², 3², ...

Comment: *All* the numbers? Really?

Answer (score 8):

The possible integer square roots are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on. So all you have to do is compute a square of every natural number and print it on screen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sth; i++) { 
    printf("%d\n", i*i);
}
```

It's also impossible to print ALL these numbers, as the set you're trying to print is infinite, unless you want your program to work endlessly (and of course it won't work properly either, since you'll get to the integer overflow point).

Comment: `printf("%lld ", i*1LL*i);`

Comment: Printing on separate lines is more consistent, and from the question, if a limit is set, it should be tested against the square.

Answer (score 4):

Loop from 1 to N and square the numbers? Assuming that N is your upper limit on the square root.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't show ***ALL*** numbers, as that is an infinite set.

If you only want to show a limited set of numbers (of *X* length), simply loop from 0 to (X - 1) and print i*i.

```
for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
   printf("%d\n", i*i);
```